# Get a queryset of objects where a field is distinct

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like the following:

```
class Reports(models.Model):
    reportid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I need to search the model by matching a search term in the name field. Then I need to return a queryset containing objects each of which have unique names which match the search term.

See the example:

```
testsearchterm = 'bs'

initreports = Reports.objects.filter(name__lower__contains=testsearchterm)

print("initreports:", initreports)
```

Result:

```
initreports: <QuerySet [<Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: Random Blood Sugar (RBS)>,
```

Now I get distinct names

```
reports = Reports.objects.filter(name__lower__contains=testsearchterm).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
print("Unique values:", reports)
```

Result:

```
Unique values: <QuerySet ['FBS', 'PPBS', 'Random Blood Sugar (RBS)', 'Sleep study to r/o Obstructive sleep apnea', 'Serum HBsAg']>
```

Now I need the full queryset not just the names, so that I can serialize the results and return the other fields too.

```
for name in tests:
    res = Reports.objects.filter(name=name).first()
    print(res, type(res))
```

Results:

```
FBS <class 'appointments.models.Reports'>
PPBS <class 'appointments.models.Reports'>
Random Blood Sugar (RBS) <class 'appointments.models.Reports'>
Sleep study to r/o Obstructive sleep apnea <class 'appointments.models.Reports'>
Serum HBsAg <class 'appointments.models.Reports'>
```

I need a queryset of the above, like the following:

```
<QuerySet [<Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: RBS>, <Reports: HBsAg>]
```

It nees to be a proper queryset and not a list or set, so that I can use DRF modelserializer as is.

An example of the data is given as reference: [image: Admin view]

N.B. `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`(mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
unique_names = [Reports.objects.filter(name=name)[0].pk for name in Reports.objects.filter(name__lower__contains=testsearchterm).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()]
query = Reports.objects.filter(pk__in=unique_names)
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended.

Answer (score -1):

You are filtering to return only the **name** from the following query set:

```
Reports.objects.filter(name__lower__contains=testsearchterm).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

If you remove the values_list call, you will get queryset instead of list of strings.

```
Reports.objects.filter(name__lower__contains=testsearchterm).distinct()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: This answer removes duplicate rows, not duplicate names. The problem is `distinct('name')` cannot be used with MySQL

Comment: No, that wont work for me, because the entire object is not unique. Only name is unique. The other fields are not. Your query will yield this: `<QuerySet [<Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: Random Blood Sugar (RBS)>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: Random Blood Sugar (RBS)>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, <Reports: PPBS>, <Reports: FBS>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>`, which is not what I want.